# using find utility to look for all .git/config files under a certain directory

Tags: bash, git

I have a certain github repo that I used to test out netlify and vuepress.  I somewhat lost track of where it is on the file system, so I was planning to use `mdfind` (I am on mac) or `find` to locate all the **.git/config** files and then grep for my github url.

But it seems surprisingly hard to convince `find` to look for **config** under the hidden **.git** directories.

I did find [How do I search all hidden files that are in hidden folders using Terminal?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/41103) and looking at it, it looks like the following would work:

`find . -name '.*' \( -type d -exec find {} \; -prune -o -print \) | egrep '/.git/config'`

but given that **config** is a highly specific file for git, I was hoping that there is a better suited `find` command that will do the trick.  I have already given up on `mdfind` as it the linked question's accepted answer is skeptical about getting it to reliably find hidden files.

Note:  not looking for answers based on the `locate` utility, or some GUI tool, this is strictly about getting `find` to do the work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `-path`.

```
find . -path '*/.git/config'
```

Comment: got it. I've used path before but did not realize that it handles nested directory patterns. 
FYI, this is what did the trick with the grep
 `find . -path '*/.git/config' -exec egrep  'github.com/jpeyret' {} \;`

Comment: ah, `-exec egrep  -H 'github.com/jpeyret' {} \;` actually, otherwise I don't get the file name.